# Compilation error in cuda kernel calling/ passing parameters

Tags: c++, cuda

In the actual code, my intention is to get the output array by comparing the input array to the scalar. Or simply output = input > scalar.

Simple sample host-side code as shown below is working as expected.

```
    float *h_data1 = (float *)malloc(W1*H1 * sizeof(float));
    bool *h_result = (bool *)malloc(H1*W2 * sizeof(bool));

    float *d_data1;      gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_data1, W1*H1 * sizeof(float)));
    bool *d_result;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_result, H1*W2 * sizeof(bool)));

    for (int i = 0; i < W1*H1; i++) h_data1[i] = (float)i;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data1, h_data1, W1*H1 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    float scalar = 2;
    compGraterRetOut<float, bool><< <outw, outh >> > (d_data1, d_result, scalar);

    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

The device side code is

```
template<typename TType, typename TTypeOut>
__global__  void compGraterRetOut(TType *dataIn, TTypeOut *dataOut, const TType scalar)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    dataOut[i] = (dataIn[i] > scalar);
}
```

Coming to the actual code, I have an image class as shown below (Only some part of the class is shown).

```
template<typename TType, ImageType TImageType>
class Image
{
public:
    Image(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint32_t depth = 1);

private:
    TType* m_data;
    uint32_t m_width;
    uint32_t m_height;
    uint32_t m_depth;
    uint32_t m_bufferSize;
};

template<typename TType, ImageType TImageType>
Image<TType, TImageType>::Image(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint32_t depth) :m_width(width), \
m_height(height), m_depth(depth)
{
    if (width == 0 || height == 0)
        return;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    //m_data = new TType[m_width * m_height * m_depth];
    gpuErrchk(cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&m_data, sizeof(TType) * m_width * m_height * m_depth));
    if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess)
    {
        m_bufferSize = m_width * m_height * m_depth;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error malloc function failed [" << cudaStatus << "]" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

To achieve the objective out = in > scalar, operator> is overloaded as shown below. This threw a compilation error as

> "member "Image::m_data [with TType=float_t,
>   TImageType=ImageType::WHD]""

the code looks as shown below.

```
inline Image<uint32_t, TImageType> Image<TType, TImageType>::operator>(TType scalar) const
{
        Image<uint32_t, TImageType> ret(m_width, m_height, m_depth);

        compGraterRetOut<TType, uint32_t> << <m_width * 4, (m_height * m_depth/4) >> > (m_data, ret.m_data, scalar);

        gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        return std::move(ret);
}
```

To fix the compilation error I changed the function operator>. Here, cuda memory is allocated inside the function instead of inside of class's contructor.

```
template<class TType, ImageType TImageType>
inline Image<uint32_t, TImageType> Image<TType, TImageType>::operator>(TType scalar) const
{
        cudaError_t cudaStatus;

        uint32_t *dataout;
        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&dataout, m_width*m_height*m_depth * sizeof(uint32_t)));

        Image<uint32_t, TImageType> ret(dataout, m_width, m_height, m_depth);

        compGraterRetOut<TType, uint32_t> << <m_width * 4, (m_height * m_depth/4) >> > (m_data, dataout, scalar);

        gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

        return std::move(ret);
}
```

Finally, my question is why last code compiled without an error, but not previous to that?

Comment: What is your compiler and OS?

Comment: And also the full error

Comment: There is no full error. I get only this much "member "Image::m_data [with TType=float_t, TImageType=ImageType::WHD]""

Compiler is nvcc v9.0 I am using Visual Studio 2015 (v140)

Comment: Linux has problem problem with templated class members you have to explicitly use this-> maybe that works for you too

Comment: I am using windows 10. ret is an object reference so cannot use ->. The problem is with ret.m_data not with this->m_data or m_data.

Comment: you used m_data of current object too

Comment: yea, I found that the problem is with ret object and not with this.

Comment: I found the reason. The problem has nothing to do with Cuda. It is the problem with templates and OOPS. When template class access a member in its own type it would not violate OOPS paradigm. Accessing a private member of the same class with different template arguments violate the OOPS paradigm. That is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with Cuda. It is the problem with templates and OOPS. When template class access a member in its own type it would not violate OOPS paradigm. Accessing a private member of the same class with different template arguments violate the OOPS paradigm. That is the answer.

Comment: Please remember to come back in a few days and accept you answer so that this question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag